# Jest - Getting Started lesson not completely

Tags: tdd, jestjs

I'm using w/ VScode on a mac. I followed the instructions for the first test on https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started.

I'm getting a jest prompt - and it's just hanging. The test is not completing.

Jest is installed and my package.json is set up.  What's is going on? I'd love to start doing TDD.

Comment: do you have created any test? how do you run it? through VS? with terminal?

Comment: Looks like there are conflicts with watchman.  Various solutions on gitHub.  Upgrading (in homebrew) to watchman 4.9 resolved the issue for me. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2219